# Acting upon a Hasan (good) Hadith?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, uloom-al-hadith

What is the attitude of the scholars concerning a hadeeth that is classified hasan (good) hadith, be used as evidence in islam and can we act upon it?

Comment: A hadith hassan is by default a hadith which is sahih but has not the necessary tawatur! So it is a hadith we should follow if it neither contradicts neither the Quran nor any sahih (mutawatir) hadith! Note that in both sahihs books there are around 200 narrations which strictly speaking are even only ahaad so they don't even reach the grade of a hassan hadith!

Comment: From which aspect are you asking about applicability of _hassan_ hadith to scholars? As in evidence for interpretation of Qur'an, other hadiths, rulings, manners, worship, etc.?